# Can we have both ARM and x86 images in the same Docker Hub repo?

Tags: dockerhub

What's the best way to have both ARM and x86 images on Docker Hub so people can choose according to their platform? Both images should be in sync (i.e. :latest on ARM should bring the latest ARM image and :latest on x86 should bring the latest x86 image).

Answer (score 0):

It's been supported now by docker a feature called manifest. [Here](https://integratedcode.us/2016/04/22/a-step-towards-multi-platform-docker-images/) is the reference news, FYI.